# Is there a Redo (Undo Undo) function in Super Mario Maker 2?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

If I use the Undo Dog to Undo one step too far in Super Mario Maker 2, is there any way to *redo*? For example if I forget what my third last action was and I undo 3 times, and realize that I actually *wanted* that 3rd action, can I undo *the Undo Dog action itself* and go "forward" a step?

Comment: sadly no ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is. You just have to be careful with your undo's. Make sure to save regularly too. (Correct me if I am wrong).